# delete records from staging table after they have been added to the real table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have an asp.net program, that adds tasks to my staging table and executes a stored procedure that takes these tasks and places them in my actual table, i would like to delete the records after they are added, because my staging table will get too big fast.

here is my stored procedure code

```
    INSERT INTO dashboardtasks
SELECT [tour], tourname, [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], completed , canceled
FROM staggingtasks
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM dashboardtasks 
                 WHERE (staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
                       staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate and 
staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks.duedate and
staggingtasks.tourname=dashboardtasks.tourname 

)
                 )




END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you could do the `DELETE` from your staging table combined with the `OUTPUT` clause. and `INSERT` the result of the `OUTPUT` clause into your main table to do this all in one atomic statement.

```
OUTPUT deleted.* into dashboardtasks
```

There are [some restrictions listed in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) though which may make this approach unviable.

The output_table cannot:

- Have enabled triggers defined on it.
- Participate on either side of a
  foreign key constraint.
- Have CHECK
  constraints or enabled rules.

Full syntax for your query...

```
DELETE FROM staggingtasks
OUTPUT DELETED.[tour],
       DELETED.tourname,
       DELETED.[taskname],
       DELETED.[deptdate],
       DELETED.[tasktype],
       DELETED.[desc],
       DELETED.[duedate],
       DELETED.[compdate],
       DELETED.[comments],
       DELETED.[agent],
       DELETED.[compby],
       DELETED.[graceperiod],
       DELETED.completed,
       DELETED.canceled
INTO dashboardtasks
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   dashboardtasks
                  WHERE  ( staggingtasks.tour = dashboardtasks.tour
                           and staggingtasks.taskname = dashboardtasks.taskname
                           and staggingtasks.deptdate = dashboardtasks.deptdate
                           and staggingtasks.duedate = dashboardtasks.duedate
                           and staggingtasks.tourname = dashboardtasks.tourname
                         ))
```

Comment: and does this mean that after the task is added it will then be deleted right after

Comment: that's an awesome way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

Have a delete statement with the same criteria you have for insert except that you now use **EXISTS** instead of **NOT EXISTS**.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dashboardtasks
SELECT [tour], tourname, [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], completed , canceled
  FROM staggingtasks
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
        SELECT * 
         FROM dashboardtasks 
         WHERE (
                        staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
                      staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
                        staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate and 
                        staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks.duedate and
                        staggingtasks.tourname=dashboardtasks.tourname 
                    )
  )


DELETE FROM staggingtasks
 WHERE EXISTS
  (
        SELECT * 
         FROM dashboardtasks 
         WHERE (
                        staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
                      staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
                        staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate and 
                        staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks.duedate and
                        staggingtasks.tourname=dashboardtasks.tourname 
                    )
  )
```

Comment: +1 If the number of records is large, you could move the delete to an hourly cleanup job, so the program itself can continue

Answer (score 2):

Remember that deleting will log everything so in time your log may grow too big. If you don't care about the data in your staging table, then try the TRUNCATE command instead after your insert:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE staggingtasks
```

Like others are saying, you may want to put it all into Transactions *just in case*. The plus about Truncate is that it is fast since no additional logging is required for each record you are purging from the table.

Comment: What happens if another call has been made to the stored procedure and the first call has finished and dumped the data?  I'm not being picky, just curious :o)

Comment: Well just like a delete. If the first call has completed and dumped the data (whether through DELETE or TRUNCATE), it's gone. The second call will return nothing. My whole point was to give another means to do the same thing. Deleting logs every row that you are deleting. Truncating doesn't.

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE can be rolled back in a transaction too... so +1

Answer (score 1):

If things could be happening concurrently (in particular if the staggingtasks can be inserted into while the other process happens),  then none of the existing solutions are safe.

You need to Insert the data to a temp table, then insert the data from the temp table and then delete the data from the staging table based on the records in the temp table. This ensures you only deleted the records you inserted and not some others added while the insert happens. And of course you should put all this in a transaction as @Ardman showed.

Further you should not ever do an insert without specifying the fields you are inserting into. Suppose someone recreated the table and rearranged the fields, then your insert would insert into the wrong fields (if the datatypes are compatible)  or fail.

```
SELECT [tour], tourname, [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], completed , canceled 
INTO #TasksToInsert
FROM staggingtasks 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM dashboardtasks 
                WHERE (staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks.tour 
                    AND staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname 
                    AND staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate 
                    AND staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks.duedate 
                    AND staggingtasks.tourname=dashboardtasks.tourname)
                )

INSERT INTO dashboardtasks ([tour], tourname, [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], completed , canceled )
SELECT [tour], tourname, [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod], completed , canceled 
FROM #TasksToInsert

DELETE FROM staggingtasks  
WHERE EXISTS   (SELECT *
                FROM #TasksToInsert          
                WHERE (staggingtasks.tour=#TasksToInsert.tour 
                        AND staggingtasks.taskname=#TasksToInsert.taskname 
                        AND staggingtasks.deptdate=#TasksToInsert.deptdate 
                        AND staggingtasks.duedate=#TasksToInsert.duedate 
                        AND staggingtasks.tourname=#TasksToInsert.tourname)
                )
```

And if this hasn't gone to production yet, please fix the misspelling of StagingTasks. Or it will annoy your developers for years! I would also consider putting in a surrogate key to the dashboardTasks table as a multiple field PK like you have is likely to cause performance issues that a smaller int key would not especially if there are child tables. But still make a unique index on the natural key.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `DELETE` statement that cleans out the table

`DELETE FROM myTable`

My suggestion would be to use `BEGIN TRY` and `BEGIN CATCH` so if anything happens you haven't deleted the data from the staging table.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT statement....

    // All successful
    DELETE statement...

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN

END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Possible race condition with concurrent inserts though unless the OP knows there won't be any or takes a table lock.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple queries in a single stored procedure, so unless I'm missing something you should just be able to add

```
DELETE staggingtasks WHERE <any criteria you need>
```

after the INSERT query...