# Will TOP always return the same rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written some code to move data into an archive table, 1000 rows at a time (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
-- archive data
while (@QuitLoop = 0)
begin  
 begin transaction

  insert into MyTransactionTable (...) 
  select top 1000 * from MyTransactionTable where DateOfSale < @ArchiveCutOffDate       

  delete top 1000 from MyTransactionTable where DateOfSale < @ArchiveCutOffDate         

  if (@@rowcount = 0) select @QuitLoop = 1
 commit transaction
end
```

Will top always returns the same 1000 rows?

So the rows being inserted into the archive table are the same as the rows being deleted form the transaction table.

Comment: You might be able to use the `OUTPUT` clause for this (there are some restrictions on when it can be used in this manner). See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019665/delete-records-from-staging-table-after-they-have-been-added-to-the-real-table/5019789#5019789) for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are using them no, they will *not* be guaranteed to return the same rows.

Why? Because you don't specify an `order by` clause. It'll just be whatever 1000 records the engine decides are the 'top' ones that time around.

Also note that it's possible even if you specify an `order by` that you still wouldn't get the same 1000 rows... if your order by is not selective enough that on the border of the 1000th item is a specific, definable order.

For example; if there are 1002 items with the same sorted value at the top, you don't know which 2 would *not* be included.